# Unable to delete a record when created foreign-key constraints manually in mysql without using migration.

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have created database tables manually and i have also created foreign key constraints in tables manually without using migration. now when i am going to delete a record it giving me following error-

> Integrity constraint violation:  Cannot delete or update a parent row:
>   a foreign key constraint fails

**Note:** i can't use migration because database was already created.

Comment: It's obvious that you have created `foreign key constraints` so you need to delete all child first and then parent. No matter how you created this with or without migrations

Comment: You may not have used onDelete Cascade and onUpdate Cascade!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ON DELETE CASCADE` and `ON UPDATE CASCADE` on foreign keys, like:

```
...(create/alter Children table query)...
CONSTRAINT FK_ParentChild
FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES Parents(id) 
ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

So you don't have to manually delete children before deleting the parent element. All children records will automatically delete along with the deletion of parent record.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest investigating this further by doing the follow:

1. On your development environment, write migrations to create the
   tables from scratch 2)
2. Look at the generated schema and compare it
   to the schema of your existing production tables
3. Note the
   differences between the two schema and write migrations to correct
   the production tables.

**Note:**

If you need to correct the data in the meantime ***and you are confident that the data integrity of your database is not at risk***. You can use the following statements to drop the foreign key checks whilst you correct the data.

`SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;`

`SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;`

I can't stress enough, **remember to turn on your foreign key checks once you are finished and do not do this on a production database**. Take a copy of the database and try things locally until you are confident that your corrections are 100% safe ;)